# How can I replace recurring values in a numpy array by the index of the unique value from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array a with recurring elements, and a second array, b, containing the sorted, unique values from a (as well as an auxilliary "index array", c):

```
a = np.array(['Bob', 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Charly', 'Bob'])
b = sorted(np.unique(a))
c = np.arange(len(b))
>>> b
array(['Anna', 'Bob', 'Charly'])
>>> c
array([0, 1, 2])
```

What I would like to have is an array, d, where the values from a are replaced by their index in b. The expected result should look like this:

```
>>>d
array([1, 0, 1, 2, 1])
```

Any suggestions how to get the expected result would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create `b` or `c`, you can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and have it return the `inverse`:

```
d = np.unique(a, return_inverse = True)[1]                                                           
>>> d
array([1, 0, 1, 2, 1])
```

For reference:

> return_inverse : bool, optional
>
> If True, also return the indices of the unique array (for the specified axis, if provided) that can be used to reconstruct ar.

## Alternative pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Categorical(a).codes
array([1, 0, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
d = [b.index(i) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Avin's answer you can do

```
a = ['Bob', 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Charly', 'Bob']
b = sorted(list(set(a)))
c = [b.index(x) for x in a]
```

However, just wanted to add that numpy is a numerical computing library. You can/should just use lists for this.